# Mask certain file paths in binary files

Tags: binary

I have a binary file containing some file paths. If the path starts with a certain string, the rest of the file path `[\x20-\x7f]+` should be masked, leaving the general structure and size of the file intact!

So with a list of paths to search for is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/
/home/joe/
```

Then an occurrence like this in the binary data:

```
^@^@^@^@/home/joe/documents/hello.docx^@^@^@^@
```

Should be changed to this:

```
^@^@^@^@/home/joe/********************^@^@^@^@
```

What is the best way to do this? Do sed, perl or awk have a way? Or do I have to write a C or PHP program where I find the string and write `strlen()` number of mask characters in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` is a good choice for working on binary data. For `sed` and `awk`, only the GNU implementations can generally cope with binary data, the other ones would choke on the NUL byte or on long sequences between two newline characters, or on non-terminated lines.

```
perl -pi.back -e 's{(/usr/local/bin|/home/joe)/\K[\x20-\x7f]+}{
  $& =~ s/./*/rg}ge' binary-file
```

You'd need not too old a version of `perl` for the `/r` flag (returns the result of the substitution instead of applying it on the variable) and `\K` (reset the start of the matched string).

By default, `perl -p` works on one line at a time, since the newline character is not part of `[\x20-\x7f]`, that's fine.

Comment: This solution worked straight out of the box! Great for anonymising personal information in log files. (There's a missing `/` behind `bin`, but that's details!)

Comment: @forthrin. Thanks, I've now moved the trailing `/` out of the alternation so it applies to both paths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some perl code that works, though I'm sure it can be optimised.  It is a filter, so it reads all of stdin into `$data`, then for each string in the array `@dirs` it does a substitute for the pattern. The replacement however is not a fixed string but a function call `replace($dir,$1)` which is evaluated because of the `e` modifier to the substitute command.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
sub replace{
    my ($dir,$rest) = @_;
    $rest =~ s/./*/g;
    return $dir.$rest;
}
my @dirs = ('/usr/local/bin/','/home/joe/');
my $data = join("",<STDIN>);
foreach my $dir (@dirs){
    $data =~ s|$dir([\x20-\x7f]+)|replace($dir,$1)|ge;
}
print $data;
```

The function is given 2 arguments, the directory and the captured part of the pattern. It returns these concatenated after replacing each character in the captured string.